# probability of choosing one object out of 3 from 10 total

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm stuck on the following question.

Say you have 10 objects, of which one is a red object. Say, you choose 3 of the 10 objects at random. What is the probability that the red object is in the 3 that you choose?

So far, I know that there are 10 choose 3 = 120 ways to choose 3 objects from 10. But, I don't know how the 1 red object fits into this calculation.

Thanks!

Comment: How many ways are there to choose $3$ objects so that one of them is the red object? You have to choose the red object, and then given that, how many ways are there to choose $2$ objects from the remaining $9$?

Answer (score 0):

The probability is $\frac{\binom{9}{2}}{\binom{10}{3}}$ because the red one must be in the $3$ objects so we choose $\binom{9}{2}$.